# How to fit a second column under another in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am showing one element after the other for XS and SM, but for MD I want to show one image on the left and two elements on the right column, I couldn't find a way to fit the second column under the right one. Here is what I want to do

```
Mobile (this is working)
----------------------
*Title*
*Description*
*Image*
*Icons*
----------------------

Now for >= MD (Not Working)
----------------------
*Image* | *Title*
        | *Description*
        | *Icons* 
----------------------
```

I couldn't find a way to fit description and Icons under title. Here is my code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <p>Data</p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-pull-6 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-1 main-tour">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.a1smallbusinessmarketing.com/images/prosbo_hires.jpg"/>
            </div>
        <div class="main-tour">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-offset-1 items m-t-3">
                        <div>1</div>
                        <div>2</div>
                        <div>3</div>
                        <div>4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paqycmh9/)

Any ideas how this could be implemented?

Comment: If it fixed your problem please mark as correct and vote up or tell me more if it has any problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paqycmh9/2/). Use media queries for screen sizes and apply your css.

```
@media (min-width:420px) and (max-width:1040px){
  .main-tour{
    float:left;
  }

  .row .first, .row .main-tour{
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .main-tour.description{
    display:block;
    float:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the solution works great! One question, could you explain how the inline-block works in this particular case? Because I applied to my live version and the 'main-tour' div doesn't go under the title; I know in this version works but in mine it doesn't and I cannot find the solution. Thanks

Comment: When you use the display:inline-block; the elements will be displayed inline. The must important thing here in my solution is the .description{float:none;} this is what makes the hole thing work :) Thumb up :D

Comment: Edisoni your answer was very clear. I am banging my head with the wall. There is some sort of conflict between the CSS of my entire website and this particular part where you commented, if you have some minutes would you take a look https://jsfiddle.net/paqycmh9/8/ . Either way, thank you very much

Comment: Your logic is wrong here. You are using col-xs-10 for each div when the hole space is 12 so 10+10 !=12 so one of these divs will go in new row. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/paqycmh9/9/ i have make width 50% for two first divs and it works. The added css is at the end of the css. You just make them col-xs-5 or col-xs-6